# Pythonでフレームワークを使用せず、複数のHTMLページ間を遷移するようなWebアプリケーションサンプル

Tags: python

**Pythonでリンクをクリックしたら複数のHTMLページ間を遷移するような、Webアプリケーションサンプルはないでしょうか？**
・学習用途用なので、フレームワークもテンプレートも使用していないようなシンプルなコードが良いのですが…、
・「mod_wsgi ✕ Apache」で「Hello World」を表示させたところなので、その次に取り組むようなサンプルを探しています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これはどうでしょう？
サンプルではないですが、目的には合っていそうです。

基礎から学ぶWebアプリケーションフレームワークの作り方
https://pycon.jp/2016/en/schedule/presentation/14/